# Argument required error when using Ag with vim

Tags: vim, ag

I'd like to just use the `:Ag` command to enter the interactive ag shell (as with `:Files`) and  then start typing my search term.

However, vim won't allow me to open the `ag` interactive interface. If I type `:Ag`, it will complain with the following error:

> E471: Argument required

If I write the search term (like `:Ag something`) it opens a new pane with the results. But that's not what I want: I want to use `ag` the same way as the `:Files` command.

#### More info

I'm using [thoughtbot/dotfiles](https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles).

#### Definition of `:Ag` command

```
:verbose command Ag

    Name              Args Address Complete    Definition
|   Ag                +            file        silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
```

#### Settings

This is the portion of my `.vimrc` file where `ag` is enabled.

```
" Use The Silver Searcher https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use Ag over Grep
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

  " Use ag in fzf for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag --literal --files-with-matches --nocolor --hidden -g ""'

  if !exists(":Ag")
    command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
    nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
  endif
endif
```

Comment: "I'm using thoughtbot/dotfiles." That is the cause of your problem. It is not your config so you don't know what is going on in it and when things break you don't know how to fix them. Anyway, what does `:verbose command Ag` say?

Comment: @romainl I've added the output of `:verbose command Ag` to the question above

Comment: 1. That vimrc is not *your* vimrc. 2. That command is a makeshift `:Ag` added to that file by its maintainer, that requires arguments and doesn't involve fzf at all. I would expect fzf to override that command, though.

Comment: @romainl Do you have any suggestions to use `ag` in a window (simlar to CtrlP)?

Comment: As I said, assuming you have a working `:Files` [provided by fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/plugin/fzf.vim#L61), I would expect fzf to define [its own `:Ag`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/plugin/fzf.vim#L69). If it doesn't, then there must be a problem somewhere and that ready-made config you got from the web doesn't make it easy to find out where. Maybe fzf is not correctly installed? Maybe it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

This portion of the `.vimrc` (by thoughtbot/dotfiles) was overriding the default behaviour set by `fzf.vim`:

```
if !exists(":Ag")
  command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
  nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
endif
```

I just commented it out and things are now working as I wanted.
Thanks to @romainl for giving some useful hints.